# Object copiable objective-c

Tags: objective-c, object, mutable

In my app, I have an object and I want to make a copy of it before his properties change. The class of my app has the following code:

```
@interface match : NSObject 
@property int iMatchId;
-(id) copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone;
@end
```

In the class that implements the object, I have the following code in the method "copyWithZone":

```
-(id) copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone
{
    match *matchCopy = [[match allocWithZone: zone] init];

    matchCopy.iMatchId = _iMatchId;
    return matchCopy;
}
```

When I want to copy the object, I execute the following code:

```
_oOldMatch = [_oMatch copy];
```

But if I change the variable `_oMatch` then the variable `_oOldMatch` it changes.

I don´t know if I am doing anything bad.

Comment: Class names have uppercase letters in ObjC, and there is no hungarian notation (the `i` and `o` prefixes you're using). Writing in non-standard style will break key-value coding, and is very hard to read for ObjC devs.

Comment: Also, I cannot reproduce this behavior using the above code. It behaves as expected. Please provide a MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Update your question showing code that demonstrates the problem. Show how you change `_oMatch` and how you determined that both changed as a result.

Comment: Miguel, this code snippet (naming conventions notwithstanding) is fine. If the property was a mutable object (e.g. a `NSMutableArray` or something like that) rather than a fundamental data type (e.g. an `int`), then you might see the problem you describe (but it would be easily solved if you made the property a `copy` type). But for `int` property, this is fine. As an aside, in addition to Rob's naming convention observation, I might also be inclined to explicitly specify that this conforms to `NSCopying` (it's a good way to be safe and minimize chances to introduce typos in method names).